# How to print a value from foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

How print the `$ingPre[$prc]` this is my result when the variable `$prc` changes, this variable `prc` compare, if `Lic` changes values from the internal foreach variables, for example

```
echo $ingPre['Lic']; 
echo $ingPre['Doc'];

//this is my code
$preAntSQ = $mysql->query('
        SELECT pre_red, plan
        FROM pcps
        WHERE id_sede = "'.$sede.'"
            AND univ = "SUG CEN"
            AND fecha = "'.($dateY - 2).'"
    ');

while($preAntSQR = $mysql->f_array($preAntSQ)){
        $planOpr['plan'] = $precioAntSQR['plan'];
        $preAntSF[$preAntSQR['plan']] = $preAntSQR['pre_red'];
    }


foreach($planOpr as $prc){
        $prePre[$prc] = ($preAntSF[$prc] * (1 + $inflacionSF[$prc])) * (1 - $becaPreSF[$prc]);
        $ingPreSF[$prc] = ($prePre[$prc] - $preDcto[$prc]) * 4 * $meta[$prc];
        $ingPre[$prc] = '$ '.number_format($ingPreSF[$prc], 0);
    }
```

Comment: Probably want to put some tags on this to indicate what programming language, etc, so you'll get more visibility to the people who know the technology.

Comment: please tag with the language of this script. also, it is not clear what are you asking.

Comment: http://php.net/echo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ingPre` is array, so:

You can show it using `var_dump/print_r`:

```
print_r($ingPre);
```

You can `echo` direct value, if you know `$prc`:

```
$prc = 2;
echo $ingPre[$prc] // or echo $ingPre[2]
```

You can use foreach to go through whole array:

```
foreach ($ingPre as $key => $val) {
    echo $key . ': ' . $val . '<br>';
}
```